# How can I Dynamically switch a component into another page using <Link to=

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Please help me out with this as I am learning on my own.
I have a list of shops rendering using .map, now I want to render the shops that users click on.
I have my BarberShops imported and tried to use Link from React-Router to go to the next page on my barberShopHandler, but didn't work.
on my shopList component I have :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "../List.css";

class ShopList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-item">
        <div className="listing" onClick={this.props.click}>
          <div className="listing-main">
            <h3 className="listing-title">{this.props.shop}</h3>
            <p className="listing-subtitle">{this.props.address}</p>
            <p className="listing-opening-hours"> {this.props.operation}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ShopList;
```

on my List component I have :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./List.css";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";
import Map from "./Map/Map";
import ShopList from "./components/ShopList";
// import BarberShop1 from "../barberShop/BarberShop1";
// import BarberShop2 from "../barberShop/BarberShop2";

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shops: [
        {
          id: "0",
          shopName: " my shop name",
          address: "my shop address",
          operatingHour: "Open (9:00 - 20:00)",
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          shopName: " my shop name",
          address: " my shop address",
          operatingHour: "Open (10:00 - 20:00)",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  barberShopHandler = (index) => {
    const shops = this.state.shops;
    if (index === shops[0].id) {
       **<Link to="/barbershop1">
          <BarberShop1 />
        </Link>;** ***which didnt work***
      console.log(shops[0].id);
    } else if (index === shops[1].id) {
      console.log(shops[1].id);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const shops = this.state.shops;
    return (
      <div>
        <Map />
        <Footer />
        <div className="list-wrapper" style={{ transform: `translateY(1px)` }}>
          {shops.map((shop, index) => {
            return (
              <ShopList
                key={shop.id}
                shop={shop.shopName}
                address={shop.address}
                operation={shop.operatingHour}
                click={() => this.barberShopHandler(index)}
              ></ShopList>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="list-refresh">
          <button className="refresh-button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default List;
```

**update **
and my router file

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Login = lazy(() => import("./pages/login/Login"));
const List = lazy(() => import("./pages/list/List"));
const BarberShop1 = lazy(() => import("./pages/barberShop/BarberShop1"));
const BarberShop2 = lazy(() => import("./pages/barberShop/BarberShop2"));

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <Redirect from="/" to="/login" />
          <Route path="/list" component={List} />
          <Route path="/barbershop1" component={BarberShop1} />
          <Route path="/barbershop2" component={BarberShop2} />
        </Suspense>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I want to render BarberShop1 or BarberShop2 depending on what user click on

Comment: The react-router (https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) documentation explains it very well. You should try to follow it and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann thanks . yes and i use  <Link to="/barbershop1">
 <BarberShop1 />
</Link> but didnt work

Comment: Did you set  up your routes as explained in the documentation? What exactly did not work? Your provided code does not include any react-router code, it's literally impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann sorry, I didn't want to put all my code here. but yes and I will update my code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Link` is use to create links. It cannot be used after you click to send somewhere..

You could use the `history` prop passed from the router to the `List` component

```
  barberShopHandler = (index) => {
    const shops = this.state.shops;
    if (index === shops[0].id) {
      this.props.history.push("/barbershop1");
    } else if (index === shops[1].id) {
      this.props.history.push("/barbershop2");
    }
  };
```

---

But a cleaner / more extensible way would be to add the url of each shop to its object and then use the `Link` in the `ShopList`

So in `List` component

```
this.state = {
  shops: [
    {
      id: "0",
      shopName: " my shop name",
      address: "my shop address",
      operatingHour: "Open (9:00 - 20:00)",
      link: '/barbershop1'
    },
    {
      id: "1",
      shopName: " my shop name",
      address: " my shop address",
      operatingHour: "Open (10:00 - 20:00)",
      link: '/barbershop2'
    },
  ],
};
```

and

```
     {shops.map((shop, index) => {
        return (
          <ShopList
            key={shop.id}
            shop={shop.shopName}
            address={shop.address}
            operation={shop.operatingHour}
            link={shop.link}
          ></ShopList>
        );
      })}
```

and in `ShopList`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import "../List.css";

class ShopList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-item">
        <Link to={this.props.link} className="listing" onClick={this.props.click}>
          <div className="listing-main">
            <h3 className="listing-title">{this.props.shop}</h3>
            <p className="listing-subtitle">{this.props.address}</p>
            <p className="listing-opening-hours"> {this.props.operation}</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ShopList;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to wrap the `Link` around your Barbershop component:
The `onClick` logic is contained within the Link itself.

```js
{shops.map((shop, index) => {
    return (
      <Link to={`/barbershop${index}`} key={shop.id}>
        <ShopList
          shop={shop.shopName}
          address={shop.address}
          operation={shop.operatingHour}
          click={() => this.barberShopHandler(index)}
        ></ShopList>
      </Link>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: My bad, the key also has to be moved to the Link component. I've updated the answer. For more info on why you need keys: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html